# UK Zip Code List - Nearest Five Zip List

Tags: database, postal-code

Does anyone know of a free postcode CSV for UK? I have one for the USA but can't fined a UK equivalent.

I want to implement nearest Five kind of logic based on long, Lat.

Kindly let me know if any one is aware.

Regards,
Jigar

Comment: UK doesn't have ZIP codes. The US Post Office invented them and they're no used anywhere else.

Comment: @Gabe So I live in "no anywhere else" :)

Comment: Ok so how to do the same for UK clients?

Comment: belisarius: Assuming you're from Argentina, you would use CPAs (8 character Codigo Postal Argentino) as postal codes instead of ZIP codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to explore the [Ordnance Survey OpenData dataset](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/opendata/).

The UK doesn't have zip codes; rather, it has [postcodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_the_United_Kingdom), which are much more precise. For example the building where I work has a postcode to itself, BS1 2PH.

Commercial organisations that validate postcodes use the [Postcode Address File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcode_Address_File), which is commercially licensed (and expensive!), mostly as maintaining a per-premise address format is very time-consuming.

In practice most Web sites. etc. use Web services such as [Postcode Anywhere](http://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/demos/address-finder.aspx) which aggregate and resell the data.